# LibGDX - Independent intersector for detecting collisions

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, physics, game-engine

Does LibGDX have independent from snapshots collision detector? For instance, I don't want to use `Box2D` and want to detect collision of very fast objects. I know that it has `Intersector` class which is designed for this purpose, but I can't use it for very fast objects, because it doesn't work for them. So, does LibGDX have this kind of class or I should implement them by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing sort of that in libgdx. It canbe achieved through box2d but you didnt want that... So you have to write something on your own.

I think your problem is if the object is too fast that it passes other object completely without giving any collison callback.

Basically what you want is predictive collision. It means you find that collision is going to occur one step before. and then act accordingly..

try this

http://seb.ly/2010/01/predictive-collision-detection-techniques/

Answer (score 2):

LibGDX does not have anything built-in to do swept collision detection/response (aside from what Box2D provides).

Here's an article on gamedev.net that covers it if you implement your own:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/swept-aabb-collision-detection-and-response-r3084

Answer (score 2):

I have found implementation of different collision detection such as `circle and line` or `circle and circle`. But it is in russian language and for `Macromedia Flash MX`: [swept collision detection](http://animbook.mirmap.com/content/view/32/43/)
If someone has wish to convert those functions to Java, you are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Rectangle or Circle for bounds
U can use

```
Rectangle bound1=new Rectangle(0,0,10,10);
Circle c=new Circle(0,0,10);

if(c.contains(vector.x,vector.y))
{
//do something
}

if(bound1.contains(vector.x,vector.y))
{
//do something
}
```

This should help u out

Comment: I don't think that it helps me to solve my problem with very fast objects!